# How do I put a list to a .txt file, which each value in the list having its own line in R?

Tags: r

My list is here. I want this to be outputed to a .txt file.

```
> rowNames_res_all_filtered
  [1] "ENSMUSG00000000088.7"  "ENSMUSG00000000197.8"  "ENSMUSG00000000305.12" "ENSMUSG00000000838.17" "ENSMUSG00000001467.5"  "ENSMUSG00000002006.12"
  [7] "ENSMUSG00000002031.13" "ENSMUSG00000002055.9"  "ENSMUSG00000002222.14" "ENSMUSG00000002325.15" "ENSMUSG00000002379.7"  "ENSMUSG00000002477.5" 
 [13] "ENSMUSG00000002831.14" "ENSMUSG00000002985.16" "ENSMUSG00000003032.8"  "ENSMUSG00000003228.9"  "ENSMUSG00000003308.15" "ENSMUSG00000003469.9" 
 [19] "ENSMUSG00000003617.16" "ENSMUSG00000003814.8"  "ENSMUSG00000003849.8"  "ENSMUSG00000003949.16" "ENSMUSG00000003974.6"  "ENSMUSG00000004328.15"
 [25] "ENSMUSG00000004798.14" "ENSMUSG00000004865.16" "ENSMUSG00000004902.7"  "ENSMUSG00000005045.16" "ENSMUSG00000005360.14" "ENSMUSG00000005447.12"
 [31] "ENSMUSG00000006057.15" "ENSMUSG00000006127.9"  "ENSMUSG00000006356.10" "ENSMUSG00000006362.16" "ENSMUSG00000006476.19" "ENSMUSG00000006958.14"
 [37] "ENSMUSG00000007476.18" "ENSMUSG00000007682.6"  "ENSMUSG00000007721.6"  "ENSMUSG00000007836.6"  "ENSMUSG00000007850.16" "ENSMUSG00000007892.8" 
 [43] "ENSMUSG00000008140.18" "ENSMUSG00000008489.18" "ENSMUSG00000008540.11" "ENSMUSG00000008730.17" "ENSMUSG00000009406.13" "ENSMUSG00000010064.15"
 [49] "ENSMUSG00000010608.15" "ENSMUSG00000010663.5"  "ENSMUSG00000013523.13" "ENSMUSG00000014226.10" "ENSMUSG00000015568.16" "ENSMUSG00000015656.17"
 [55] "ENSMUSG00000015806.12" "ENSMUSG00000015846.15" "ENSMUSG00000015852.13" "ENSMUSG00000015944.9"  "ENSMUSG00000017009.3"  "ENSMUSG00000017639.13"
 [61] "ENSMUSG00000017707.9"  "ENSMUSG00000018102.5"  "ENSMUSG00000018401.17" "ENSMUSG00000019124.10" "ENSMUSG00000019232.14" "ENSMUSG00000019432.15"
 [67] "ENSMUSG00000019726.12" "ENSMUSG00000019802.13" "ENSMUSG00000019804.12" "ENSMUSG00000019851.8"  "ENSMUSG00000019874.11" "ENSMUSG00000019880.10"
 [73] "ENSMUSG00000019947.10" "ENSMUSG00000019966.18" "ENSMUSG00000019970.15" "ENSMUSG00000020048.13" "ENSMUSG00000020077.14" "ENSMUSG00000020111.15"
 [79] "ENSMUSG00000020263.14" "ENSMUSG00000020321.16" "ENSMUSG00000020368.15" "ENSMUSG00000020396.8"  "ENSMUSG00000020591.11" "ENSMUSG00000020601.8" 
 [85] "ENSMUSG00000020607.7"  "ENSMUSG00000020611.14" "ENSMUSG00000020734.13" "ENSMUSG00000020737.12" "ENSMUSG00000020777.16" "ENSMUSG00000020785.17"
 [91] "ENSMUSG00000020810.5"  "ENSMUSG00000020811.16" "ENSMUSG00000020936.8"  "ENSMUSG00000020950.10" "ENSMUSG00000020953.17" "ENSMUSG00000020964.14"
 [97] "ENSMUSG00000020990.5"  "ENSMUSG00000021097.15" "ENSMUSG00000021130.8"  "ENSMUSG00000021196.14" "ENSMUSG00000021215.15" "ENSMUSG00000021303.14"
[103] "ENSMUSG00000021373.16" "ENSMUSG00000021379.2"  "ENSMUSG00000021520.4"  "ENSMUSG00000021557.15" "ENSMUSG00000021559.14" "ENSMUSG00000021598.9" 
[109] "ENSMUSG00000021670.14" "ENSMUSG00000021701.8"  "ENSMUSG00000021708.17" "ENSMUSG00000021721.5"  "ENSMUSG00000021750.16" "ENSMUSG00000021759.14"
[115] "ENSMUSG00000021775.11" "ENSMUSG00000021792.15" "ENSMUSG00000021794.16" "ENSMUSG00000021810.3"  "ENSMUSG00000021892.14" "ENSMUSG00000021994.15"
[121] "ENSMUSG00000022040.8"  "ENSMUSG00000022043.19" "ENSMUSG00000022055.7"  "ENSMUSG00000022103.10" "ENSMUSG00000022122.15" "ENSMUSG00000022136.8" 
[127] "ENSMUSG00000022272.17" "ENSMUSG00000022323.11" "ENSMUSG00000022324.15" "ENSMUSG00000022340.15" "ENSMUSG00000022389.15" "ENSMUSG00000022419.16"
[133] "ENSMUSG00000022425.16" "ENSMUSG00000022462.7"  "ENSMUSG00000022477.13" "ENSMUSG00000022551.8"  "ENSMUSG00000022696.17" "ENSMUSG00000022710.17"
[139] "ENSMUSG00000022763.18" "ENSMUSG00000022861.17" "ENSMUSG00000022964.14" "ENSMUSG00000023019.12" "ENSMUSG00000023456.16" "ENSMUSG00000023904.10"
[145] "ENSMUSG00000023951.18" "ENSMUSG00000023988.8"  "ENSMUSG00000024066.9"  "ENSMUSG00000024091.9"  "ENSMUSG00000024222.17" "ENSMUSG00000024338.15"
[151] "ENSMUSG00000024384.4"  "ENSMUSG00000024403.16" "ENSMUSG00000024456.16" "ENSMUSG00000024558.12" "ENSMUSG00000024610.15" "ENSMUSG00000024613.16"
[157] "ENSMUSG00000024617.16" "ENSMUSG00000024750.11" "ENSMUSG00000024853.10" "ENSMUSG00000024883.8"  "ENSMUSG00000025025.14" "ENSMUSG00000025151.16"
[163] "ENSMUSG00000025203.6"  "ENSMUSG00000025220.8"  "ENSMUSG00000025270.13" "ENSMUSG00000025290.17" "ENSMUSG00000025393.12" "ENSMUSG00000025492.6" 
[169] "ENSMUSG00000025498.15" "ENSMUSG00000025586.17" "ENSMUSG00000025738.8"  "ENSMUSG00000025780.7"  "ENSMUSG00000026020.9"  "ENSMUSG00000026072.12"
[175] "ENSMUSG00000026090.16" "ENSMUSG00000026104.14" "ENSMUSG00000026155.13" "ENSMUSG00000026158.11" "ENSMUSG00000026255.15" "ENSMUSG00000026380.10"
[181] "ENSMUSG00000026437.11" "ENSMUSG00000026463.17" "ENSMUSG00000026473.16" "ENSMUSG00000026490.18" "ENSMUSG00000026603.13" "ENSMUSG00000026615.14"
[187] "ENSMUSG00000026623.16" "ENSMUSG00000026656.15" "ENSMUSG00000026663.6"  "ENSMUSG00000026748.13" "ENSMUSG00000026864.13" "ENSMUSG00000026879.14"
[193] "ENSMUSG00000026888.14" "ENSMUSG00000027010.16" "ENSMUSG00000027198.16" "ENSMUSG00000027221.5"  "ENSMUSG00000027227.7"  "ENSMUSG00000027296.7" 
[199] "ENSMUSG00000027346.15" "ENSMUSG00000027347.18" "ENSMUSG00000027457.15" "ENSMUSG00000027533.10" "ENSMUSG00000027562.12" "ENSMUSG00000027605.18"
[205] "ENSMUSG00000027642.15" "ENSMUSG00000027751.13" "ENSMUSG00000027803.14" "ENSMUSG00000027808.8"  "ENSMUSG00000027828.12" "ENSMUSG00000027834.15"
[211] "ENSMUSG00000028124.15" "ENSMUSG00000028194.15" "ENSMUSG00000028268.14" "ENSMUSG00000028270.12" "ENSMUSG00000028337.14" "ENSMUSG00000028517.8" 
[217] "ENSMUSG00000028518.8"  "ENSMUSG00000028519.16" "ENSMUSG00000028645.11" "ENSMUSG00000028756.12" "ENSMUSG00000028790.13" "ENSMUSG00000028803.18"
[223] "ENSMUSG00000028811.12" "ENSMUSG00000028820.13" "ENSMUSG00000028861.13" "ENSMUSG00000028876.7"  "ENSMUSG00000028937.14" "ENSMUSG00000028957.12"
[229] "ENSMUSG00000028964.14" "ENSMUSG00000028986.12" "ENSMUSG00000029036.18" "ENSMUSG00000029121.16" "ENSMUSG00000029307.7"  "ENSMUSG00000029420.14"
[235] "ENSMUSG00000029561.17" "ENSMUSG00000029608.10" "ENSMUSG00000029657.15" "ENSMUSG00000029772.17" "ENSMUSG00000029838.11" "ENSMUSG00000029869.7" 
[241] "ENSMUSG00000029998.14" "ENSMUSG00000030087.11" "ENSMUSG00000030096.8"  "ENSMUSG00000030203.17" "ENSMUSG00000030307.8"  "ENSMUSG00000030317.8" 
[247] "ENSMUSG00000030374.15" "ENSMUSG00000030465.19" "ENSMUSG00000030495.12" "ENSMUSG00000030519.14" "ENSMUSG00000030605.15" "ENSMUSG00000030616.16"
[253] "ENSMUSG00000030711.16" "ENSMUSG00000030717.9"  "ENSMUSG00000030738.11" "ENSMUSG00000030774.13" "ENSMUSG00000030788.16" "ENSMUSG00000030847.8" 
[259] "ENSMUSG00000030861.15" "ENSMUSG00000031166.13" "ENSMUSG00000031209.14" "ENSMUSG00000031380.10" "ENSMUSG00000031392.18" "ENSMUSG00000031422.16"
[265] "ENSMUSG00000031431.13" "ENSMUSG00000031453.16" "ENSMUSG00000031517.8"  "ENSMUSG00000031538.6"  "ENSMUSG00000031626.18" "ENSMUSG00000031673.6" 
[271] "ENSMUSG00000031924.4"  "ENSMUSG00000031954.6"  "ENSMUSG00000032009.8"  "ENSMUSG00000032010.15" "ENSMUSG00000032064.17" "ENSMUSG00000032172.8" 
[277] "ENSMUSG00000032181.7"  "ENSMUSG00000032350.9"  "ENSMUSG00000032402.12" "ENSMUSG00000032418.15" "ENSMUSG00000032532.7"  "ENSMUSG00000032575.16"
[283] "ENSMUSG00000032594.11" "ENSMUSG00000032802.8"  "ENSMUSG00000032839.13" "ENSMUSG00000033083.16" "ENSMUSG00000033105.12" "ENSMUSG00000033166.11"
[289] "ENSMUSG00000033184.14" "ENSMUSG00000033208.7"  "ENSMUSG00000033355.6"  "ENSMUSG00000033595.7"  "ENSMUSG00000033685.13" "ENSMUSG00000033730.4" 
[295] "ENSMUSG00000033809.15" "ENSMUSG00000033863.2"  "ENSMUSG00000033871.14" "ENSMUSG00000033880.11" "ENSMUSG00000033910.13" "ENSMUSG00000033938.5" 
[301] "ENSMUSG00000034055.16" "ENSMUSG00000034059.14" "ENSMUSG00000034158.9"  "ENSMUSG00000034472.13" "ENSMUSG00000034579.17" "ENSMUSG00000034614.14"
[307] "ENSMUSG00000034799.16" "ENSMUSG00000034892.8"  "ENSMUSG00000034910.5"  "ENSMUSG00000035048.13" "ENSMUSG00000035245.12" "ENSMUSG00000036052.14"
[313] "ENSMUSG00000036225.15" "ENSMUSG00000036304.14" "ENSMUSG00000036323.14" "ENSMUSG00000036362.2"  "ENSMUSG00000036371.6"  "ENSMUSG00000036438.14"
[319] "ENSMUSG00000036459.15" "ENSMUSG00000036510.17" "ENSMUSG00000036594.15" "ENSMUSG00000036833.16" "ENSMUSG00000036943.9"  "ENSMUSG00000037010.7" 
[325] "ENSMUSG00000037071.3"  "ENSMUSG00000037214.12" "ENSMUSG00000037235.13" "ENSMUSG00000037321.17" "ENSMUSG00000037465.10" "ENSMUSG00000037625.7" 
[331] "ENSMUSG00000037664.13" "ENSMUSG00000037679.9"  "ENSMUSG00000037703.14" "ENSMUSG00000037921.15" "ENSMUSG00000037972.7"  "ENSMUSG00000037984.9" 
[337] "ENSMUSG00000038332.13" "ENSMUSG00000038393.14" "ENSMUSG00000038400.15" "ENSMUSG00000038418.7"  "ENSMUSG00000038467.15" "ENSMUSG00000038539.15"
[343] "ENSMUSG00000038555.7"  "ENSMUSG00000038690.15" "ENSMUSG00000038776.13" "ENSMUSG00000038936.13" "ENSMUSG00000039114.16" "ENSMUSG00000039159.16"
[349] "ENSMUSG00000039474.13" "ENSMUSG00000039485.8"  "ENSMUSG00000039671.18" "ENSMUSG00000039782.15" "ENSMUSG00000039910.10" "ENSMUSG00000039913.12"
[355] "ENSMUSG00000040022.14" "ENSMUSG00000040055.9"  "ENSMUSG00000040128.9"  "ENSMUSG00000040253.15" "ENSMUSG00000040276.15" "ENSMUSG00000040289.8" 
[361] "ENSMUSG00000040363.15" "ENSMUSG00000040483.15" "ENSMUSG00000040651.9"  "ENSMUSG00000040659.3"  "ENSMUSG00000040675.17" "ENSMUSG00000040964.16"
[367] "ENSMUSG00000040997.14" "ENSMUSG00000041417.15" "ENSMUSG00000041444.14" "ENSMUSG00000041459.15" "ENSMUSG00000041548.4"  "ENSMUSG00000041556.8" 
[373] "ENSMUSG00000041571.9"  "ENSMUSG00000041674.16" "ENSMUSG00000041773.8"  "ENSMUSG00000041935.10" "ENSMUSG00000041997.16" "ENSMUSG00000042115.4" 
[379] "ENSMUSG00000042216.13" "ENSMUSG00000042305.12" "ENSMUSG00000042406.8"  "ENSMUSG00000042599.8"  "ENSMUSG00000042700.16" "ENSMUSG00000042712.10"
[385] "ENSMUSG00000042729.11" "ENSMUSG00000042793.13" "ENSMUSG00000043079.17" "ENSMUSG00000043259.15" "ENSMUSG00000043279.9"  "ENSMUSG00000043439.5" 
[391] "ENSMUSG00000043496.7"  "ENSMUSG00000043909.16" "ENSMUSG00000044352.6"  "ENSMUSG00000044674.6"  "ENSMUSG00000044847.13" "ENSMUSG00000045092.8" 
[397] "ENSMUSG00000045294.11" "ENSMUSG00000045414.7"  "ENSMUSG00000045790.10" "ENSMUSG00000046607.6"  "ENSMUSG00000046668.9"  "ENSMUSG00000046897.17"
[403] "ENSMUSG00000047216.8"  "ENSMUSG00000047259.3"  "ENSMUSG00000047261.9"  "ENSMUSG00000047414.6"  "ENSMUSG00000047459.14" "ENSMUSG00000047842.7" 
[409] "ENSMUSG00000047879.17" "ENSMUSG00000047904.6"  "ENSMUSG00000048001.7"  "ENSMUSG00000048047.3"  "ENSMUSG00000048482.14" "ENSMUSG00000049092.11"
[415] "ENSMUSG00000049583.15" "ENSMUSG00000050248.11" "ENSMUSG00000050379.15" "ENSMUSG00000051537.9"  "ENSMUSG00000052229.5"  "ENSMUSG00000052305.6" 
[421] "ENSMUSG00000052684.4"  "ENSMUSG00000052911.9"  "ENSMUSG00000053137.7"  "ENSMUSG00000053279.8"  "ENSMUSG00000053310.11" "ENSMUSG00000054072.12"
[427] "ENSMUSG00000054091.9"  "ENSMUSG00000054364.5"  "ENSMUSG00000054474.15" "ENSMUSG00000054733.9"  "ENSMUSG00000055148.7"  "ENSMUSG00000055296.14"
[433] "ENSMUSG00000055373.8"  "ENSMUSG00000055407.14" "ENSMUSG00000055633.6"  "ENSMUSG00000057359.7"  "ENSMUSG00000057649.6"  "ENSMUSG00000058013.11"
[439] "ENSMUSG00000058135.12" "ENSMUSG00000058655.9"  "ENSMUSG00000058656.13" "ENSMUSG00000058740.14" "ENSMUSG00000059325.14" "ENSMUSG00000059498.13"
[445] "ENSMUSG00000059540.15" "ENSMUSG00000059852.7"  "ENSMUSG00000059974.10" "ENSMUSG00000059991.7"  "ENSMUSG00000060152.14" "ENSMUSG00000060371.12"
[451] "ENSMUSG00000060450.14" "ENSMUSG00000060550.16" "ENSMUSG00000060586.11" "ENSMUSG00000060802.8"  "ENSMUSG00000060961.16" "ENSMUSG00000061024.8" 
[457] "ENSMUSG00000061232.16" "ENSMUSG00000061904.12" "ENSMUSG00000062270.14" "ENSMUSG00000062997.6"  "ENSMUSG00000063065.13" "ENSMUSG00000063229.15"
[463] "ENSMUSG00000063297.7"  "ENSMUSG00000063524.13" "ENSMUSG00000063558.4"  "ENSMUSG00000063802.5"  "ENSMUSG00000064125.14" "ENSMUSG00000064215.13"
[469] "ENSMUSG00000064342.1"  "ENSMUSG00000064345.1"  "ENSMUSG00000064373.12" "ENSMUSG00000066551.12" "ENSMUSG00000066687.5"  "ENSMUSG00000067212.8" 
[475] "ENSMUSG00000067879.3"  "ENSMUSG00000068696.6"  "ENSMUSG00000069072.9"  "ENSMUSG00000069516.8"  "ENSMUSG00000069874.7"  "ENSMUSG00000069895.4" 
[481] "ENSMUSG00000069917.7"  "ENSMUSG00000069919.7"  "ENSMUSG00000070319.6"  "ENSMUSG00000070327.14" "ENSMUSG00000070498.3"  "ENSMUSG00000070867.4" 
[487] "ENSMUSG00000071172.13" "ENSMUSG00000071655.12" "ENSMUSG00000072966.11" "ENSMUSG00000073411.12" "ENSMUSG00000073418.4"  "ENSMUSG00000073421.6" 
[493] "ENSMUSG00000073555.1"  "ENSMUSG00000073639.6"  "ENSMUSG00000073888.13" "ENSMUSG00000073940.3"  "ENSMUSG00000074457.10" "ENSMUSG00000074575.4" 
[499] "ENSMUSG00000074578.14" "ENSMUSG00000074637.7"  "ENSMUSG00000074736.10" "ENSMUSG00000074896.3"  "ENSMUSG00000075012.4"  "ENSMUSG00000076498.2" 
[505] "ENSMUSG00000076617.9"  "ENSMUSG00000078202.3"  "ENSMUSG00000078307.3"  "ENSMUSG00000078640.9"  "ENSMUSG00000078853.8"  "ENSMUSG00000079017.3" 
[511] "ENSMUSG00000079018.10" "ENSMUSG00000079363.7"  "ENSMUSG00000079523.8"  "ENSMUSG00000086040.8"  "ENSMUSG00000089809.9"  "ENSMUSG00000090223.2" 
[517] "ENSMUSG00000090877.3"  "ENSMUSG00000091387.2"  "ENSMUSG00000091512.5"  "ENSMUSG00000092274.3"  "ENSMUSG00000092341.3"  "ENSMUSG00000092375.1" 
[523] "ENSMUSG00000096727.3"  "ENSMUSG00000097767.8"  "ENSMUSG00000099696.6"  "ENSMUSG00000101335.1"  "ENSMUSG00000103009.1"  "ENSMUSG00000110972.1" 
[529] "ENSMUSG00000111652.1"  "ENSMUSG00000118219.1"  "ENSMUSG00000002831.14" "ENSMUSG00000003657.9"  "ENSMUSG00000009185.2"  "ENSMUSG00000019232.14"
[535] "ENSMUSG00000020000.7"  "ENSMUSG00000021337.8"  "ENSMUSG00000021803.10" "ENSMUSG00000021886.7"  "ENSMUSG00000022548.14" "ENSMUSG00000022769.9" 
[541] "ENSMUSG00000023224.12" "ENSMUSG00000024066.9"  "ENSMUSG00000024087.4"  "ENSMUSG00000024338.15" "ENSMUSG00000024610.15" "ENSMUSG00000024871.11"
[547] "ENSMUSG00000025270.13" "ENSMUSG00000025723.12" "ENSMUSG00000025888.6"  "ENSMUSG00000028186.14" "ENSMUSG00000028268.14" "ENSMUSG00000028270.12"
[553] "ENSMUSG00000029417.9"  "ENSMUSG00000029561.17" "ENSMUSG00000030711.16" "ENSMUSG00000030717.9"  "ENSMUSG00000031654.16" "ENSMUSG00000032006.15"
[559] "ENSMUSG00000032446.14" "ENSMUSG00000033355.6"  "ENSMUSG00000033880.11" "ENSMUSG00000034422.14" "ENSMUSG00000034855.13" "ENSMUSG00000036594.15"
[565] "ENSMUSG00000037010.7"  "ENSMUSG00000037254.18" "ENSMUSG00000037321.17" "ENSMUSG00000038059.7"  "ENSMUSG00000038963.15" "ENSMUSG00000039899.5" 
[571] "ENSMUSG00000040170.13" "ENSMUSG00000041390.18" "ENSMUSG00000041559.7"  "ENSMUSG00000042793.13" "ENSMUSG00000043336.14" "ENSMUSG00000047216.8" 
[577] "ENSMUSG00000048001.7"  "ENSMUSG00000048562.7"  "ENSMUSG00000052305.6"  "ENSMUSG00000052684.4"  "ENSMUSG00000054072.12" "ENSMUSG00000058135.12"
[583] "ENSMUSG00000060586.11" "ENSMUSG00000061232.16" "ENSMUSG00000063558.4"  "ENSMUSG00000067578.3"  "ENSMUSG00000068859.5"  "ENSMUSG00000069874.7" 
[589] "ENSMUSG00000069917.7"  "ENSMUSG00000069919.7"  "ENSMUSG00000073411.12" "ENSMUSG00000073418.4"  "ENSMUSG00000073421.6"  "ENSMUSG00000073555.1" 
[595] "ENSMUSG00000073940.3"  "ENSMUSG00000074896.3"  "ENSMUSG00000078853.8"  "ENSMUSG00000079017.3"  "ENSMUSG00000090942.1"  "ENSMUSG00000096883.2" 
[601] "ENSMUSG00000097322.8"  "ENSMUSG00000105843.1"  "ENSMUSG00000024610.15" "ENSMUSG00000036594.15" "ENSMUSG00000060586.11" "ENSMUSG00000069874.7" 
[607] "ENSMUSG00000073421.6"  "ENSMUSG00000000214.11" "ENSMUSG00000001023.10" "ENSMUSG00000002831.14" "ENSMUSG00000003657.9"  "ENSMUSG00000003849.8" 
[613] "ENSMUSG00000018899.16" "ENSMUSG00000019232.14" "ENSMUSG00000020424.3"  "ENSMUSG00000020932.14" "ENSMUSG00000021803.10" "ENSMUSG00000022548.14"
[619] "ENSMUSG00000022769.9"  "ENSMUSG00000022868.6"  "ENSMUSG00000024087.4"  "ENSMUSG00000024222.17" "ENSMUSG00000024338.15" "ENSMUSG00000024610.15"
[625] "ENSMUSG00000024871.11" "ENSMUSG00000025270.13" "ENSMUSG00000025492.6"  "ENSMUSG00000025888.6"  "ENSMUSG00000026380.10" "ENSMUSG00000026630.9" 
[631] "ENSMUSG00000027408.7"  "ENSMUSG00000028270.12" "ENSMUSG00000029368.10" "ENSMUSG00000030108.14" "ENSMUSG00000030711.16" "ENSMUSG00000030717.9" 
[637] "ENSMUSG00000032006.15" "ENSMUSG00000032092.5"  "ENSMUSG00000032446.14" "ENSMUSG00000033355.6"  "ENSMUSG00000033880.11" "ENSMUSG00000035493.10"
[643] "ENSMUSG00000036594.15" "ENSMUSG00000037010.7"  "ENSMUSG00000037321.17" "ENSMUSG00000038776.13" "ENSMUSG00000038963.15" "ENSMUSG00000039004.6" 
[649] "ENSMUSG00000039899.5"  "ENSMUSG00000040055.9"  "ENSMUSG00000040181.14" "ENSMUSG00000041559.7"  "ENSMUSG00000047216.8"  "ENSMUSG00000048001.7" 
[655] "ENSMUSG00000048562.7"  "ENSMUSG00000048612.16" "ENSMUSG00000052305.6"  "ENSMUSG00000052688.12" "ENSMUSG00000054072.12" "ENSMUSG00000058135.12"
[661] "ENSMUSG00000060586.11" "ENSMUSG00000061232.16" "ENSMUSG00000061878.16" "ENSMUSG00000067578.3"  "ENSMUSG00000069516.8"  "ENSMUSG00000069917.7" 
[667] "ENSMUSG00000069919.7"  "ENSMUSG00000073411.12" "ENSMUSG00000073418.4"  "ENSMUSG00000073421.6"  "ENSMUSG00000073555.1"  "ENSMUSG00000073940.3" 
[673] "ENSMUSG00000074896.3"  "ENSMUSG00000078768.2"  "ENSMUSG00000078853.8"  "ENSMUSG00000079017.3"  "ENSMUSG00000102212.1"  "ENSMUSG00000104671.1" 
[679] "ENSMUSG00000105843.1"  "ENSMUSG00000113680.1"
```

Something like this

```r
ENSMUSG00000000088.7  
ENSMUSG00000000197.8  
ENSMUSG00000000305.12
```

etc. etc.

I just don't even know where to start for this or how to do this.

Comment: Have you tried `writeLines(rowNames_res_all_filtered, "something.txt")`?

Comment: That worked. Thank you.

Comment: Untested, but could also try converting your vector to a one-column data.frame before saving.